# Parametric Equation of a 3D Helix Tube Surface?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to parameterize the **surface** of a 3D helix tube like below.

[image]

As known, a parametric **curve** only requires one parameter $t$

$x=R\sin(t)$, $y=R\cos(t)$, $z=p t$,

where $R$ is the radius, and $p$ represents the pitch.

However for a surface, I think I need at least two parameters $t_1$ and $t_2$ to represent the 3D **closed surface** of a 3D helix tube.

Here, I need $x$, $y$, and $z$ in the parametric equations to be "decoupled". i.e., I am expecting something like

$x=f_1(t_1, t_2)$, $y=f_2(t_1, t_2)$, and $z=f_3(t_1, t_2)$.

What are the expressions?

Comment: Could you try to clarify what surface it is exactly that you're trying to describe?

Comment: How do you go from a straight line to a cylinder?

Comment: @Danu Updated. Thanks!

Comment: @Bernhard Thanks for the heads-up. I understand that they are essentially the same thing, but once I decouple $x$, $y$, and $z$, I only get $1/4$ of my surface. It is not closed.

Comment: I have answered this question already before. Start with a toroid, one special case is : $ (3 + \cos u ) \cos v ,(3 + \cos u) \sin v, \sin u + 0.5 v $. The last term $ 0.5 v $ is the twistor added to the torus.